# How to configure SwiftUI TextField to submit on return, and input “\n” on shift + return

Tags: swift, swiftui, textfield

Multiline TextFields can accomodate and display strings with newlines in them.
e.g.

```
@State var text: String = “a\nb\nc\nd\ne”

var body: some View {
    TextField(“”", text: $text, axis: .vertical)
}
```

But there is seemingly no way to write newlines in TextFields, because TextField “submits” whenever user presses return key. i.e. it triggers call of the field’s `.onSubmit()` method.

A common behaviour I see, in other apps, such as Messages, and many Safari webforms, is for “return” to submit entered text, and “shift+enter” to enter a line break in text, without submitting it

I assume that the iOS Messages app is built using UITextField, not SwiftUI TextField, for the prompt field. But is there a way to get the same behaviour with SwiftUI TextField (or even TextEditor) without falling back on UIKit?

I’ve tried hacky workarounds like using `.onSubmit()` and `.focussed()` to put focus back on the TextField, and appending a newline to the text, but it doesn’t work.

Comment: Seems to work for me, I can add new lines at will, on MacOS 13.4, Xcode 14.3, tested on real ios 16 devices (not Previews).
 It could be different on older systems. You could try using `TextEditor(...)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SwiftUI - Created a multiline textfield using axis: .vertical and onSubmit won't work now](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73847538/swiftui-created-a-multiline-textfield-using-axis-vertical-and-onsubmit-wont)